# Embedding a pointed topological space into a Eilenberg-MacLane space of its homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

We let $X$ be a CW complex with a unique 0-cell, given by the basepoint $x_0$, and no $k$-cells for $0 < k < n$.  I want to show that $X$ can be embedded into a $K(\pi_{n}(X,x_0),n)$ space. I am really not sure how to get started on this. I suspect that I should somehow make a use of the CW approximation theorem but in reality I don't really know what sort of construction I should be trying to build. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: seems like a straightforward obstruction theory argument, but it's been a while since I've done one of those so give me a minute

Comment: @ziggurism take your time! I am expecting it to be sth "simple" but I haven't seen a question of this type before (this is the first time I'm doing topology) so I'm not really sure how to approach this

Comment: Eilenberg-Maclane (E-M) space is not unique. And I don't think that $X$ embeds into all of them. Take $X=S^1\vee S^2$ and $n=1$ (note that $X$ satisfies your conditions). Then $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S^1$ is $K(\mathbb{Z},1)$. But clearly $X$ does not embed into $S^1$. Did you mean that $X$ embeds into some E-M space? That question is interesting, although it is trivial for metrizable CW complexes, which embed into a contractible space (and so you take a product of that space and any E-M space). Maybe every CW complex embeds into a contractible space? Not sure.

Comment: Here’s a place to start. By hurewicz, the nth homology of X matches the nth homotopy group. And by UCT so does cohomology. But cohomology is represented by K(G,n). So this gives you your map. But I guess I don’t see why it would be an embedding.

Comment: Thanks @freakish. I guess I want to show that $X$ embed into the E-M space of its $n$th homotopy group for some $n$.

Comment: Thank @ziggurism. Unfortunately, I haven't done any homology stuff yet and apparently you don't need any "homology tools" to answer this question.

Comment: I think a purely homotopy theoretic description of the map can be given, which may be what you are looking for. But it won’t tell you whether the map is an embedding (honeomorphism onto its image). Are you sure you want that? Embedding is not a homotopically well-behaves property of a map. And will also depend on your choice of K(G,n) as freakish says.

Comment: Could we say anything at all about that map being an embedding or not? Would you be keen to give the description of that map as an answer?

Comment: Any CW complex embeds into a contractible CW complex, just iteratively add cells to kill off homotopy groups. This process can be done by only attaching disks to the appropriate dimensions, so it will remain a CW complex.

Comment: given that you want a purely homotopical answer, and reference the EM space of the nth _homotopy_ group, not homology, did you mean talk about the homology group in the title question?

Comment: Maybe instead of obstruction theory we should be thinking in terms of Postnikov theory (which is closely related). You can attach a k-cell to a CW complex, and it will kill an element of $pi_{k-1}(X)$. And it may change all the higher homotopy groups, but it will leave all lower ones unchanged. So let's just do this for all the $n+1$'th and higher homotopy groups of $X$, and that will give us our map into $K(G,n)$. Isn't this actually actually how EM spaces are constructed in Hatcher? And since it is a subcomplex, maybe it's even an embedding of the type your are seeking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any (connected?) CW complex, we may attach an $n$-cell, and the resulting subcomplex inclusion map $X\hookrightarrow X\coprod e_n$ is an isomorphism on all homotopy groups $\pi_k(X)$ for $k<n-1$, and a surjection for $k=n-1$, and has unknown or complex effect for $k>n-1.$

Basically $n$-cells are nullhomotopies of the generators of $\pi_{n-1}(X)$, and so attaching one can kill off a generator (depending on the attaching map), while leaving the lower homotopy groups unchanged.

Starting with $k=n+2$, we want to attach an $(n+2)$-cell for every element of $\pi_{n+1}(X)$ (maybe it's enough to just iterate over the generators of $\pi_{n+1}(X)$?) to kill them. This leaves all the lower homotopy groups unchanged, but can scramble the higher ones of the resulting constructed CW complex.

$$
Y^{(n+2)} = X\coprod_{i\in\pi_{n+1}(X)} e^i_{n+2}.
$$

Then we ascend the skeleton, doing the same at each higher dimension, attach an $(n+3)$-cell to $Y^{(n+2)}$ for every element of $\pi_{n+2}(Y^{(n+2)})$ to kill all the elements of $\pi_{n+2}(Y^{(n+2)})$, and call the resulting complex

$$
Y^{(n+3)} = Y^{(n+2)}\coprod_{i\in\pi_{n+2}(Y^{(n+2)})} e^i_{n+3}.
$$

Continue up all the dimensions of $X$, kill all the homotopy groups above $n$, and the resulting space $Y^{(\infty)} = \operatorname{colim} Y^{(k)}$ is a $K(G,n)$ and we have an inclusion $X \hookrightarrow K(G,n)$ as a subcomplex.

Comment: Thank you @ziggurism! So it is just the Postnikov Tower right?

Comment: @billy192 I didn't specifically invoke the Postnikov tower, but the Postnikov tower is constructed using the same lemma. The normal way the Postnikov tower works though gives you maps $K(\pi_n(X),n)\to X$ rather than the other way.

Comment: ohh I see. I hope you don't mind me asking, what do you mean when you say "unknown or complex effect"? Could you tell me what the lemma was (I have a copy of Hatcher on my desk so you can just tell me the number of the page if it's from there)?

Comment: @billy192 What did I mean by "unknown or complex effect"? Well if you start with a space that's just a 1-type (pi1 is nontrival, all the other pi_n are trivial), and you want to build a new space out of it with trivial pi1, then you will attach a 2-cell for every element of pi1. This may create some 2-spheres in your resulting space. A 2-sphere has nontrivial pi_n for _every_ n≥2. So the cost of killing all the pi1 generators of our space was to add new generators in every dimension....

Comment: ...And there's no simple formula for homotopy groups of spheres, and computing homotopy groups for complex spaces is hard. So our new 1-connected space has trivial pi_1, but likely nontrivial and hard to compute pi_n for every higher n.  But adding an n-cell cannot change pi_k for k lower than n. And it can only kill pi_n, not add complexity. So as long as we start from the low dimensions and build upward inductively, we can build a complex with whatever homotopy groups we want.

Comment: As for my lemma, I actually intended to include a reference Hatcher for that lemma and looked for it, but couldn't find it, at least not in the exact form I stated. But the thing I said is pretty close to corollary 4.12. Maybe the version i used is in another textbook, I can check when I get home.

Comment: thank you! ohh so you used that lemma (the one that is close to the corollary 4.12) to show that the inclusion induces the isomorphism on $\pi_i$ for $i < n-1$ and a surjection on $\pi_{n-1}$?

Comment: it's similar, but mine didn't have anything about relative pairs or cellular approximation

Comment: yeah, I wasn't sure how was the first statement (one about inclusion inducing the isomorphism and surjection) obtained. I guess you explain it in the next paragraph but I am still struggling to see it.

Comment: The basic idea is that an (n+1)-cell is a nullhomotopy of an n-sphere, so attaching (n+1)-cells can only decrease pi_n, never increase it. And it can't affect any lower pi_n. But it can affect higher.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, thank you. Silly question, I can just write $\pi_{n}(X)$ instead of $G$, right? $K(G,n)$ is just an abuse of notation?

Comment: I am sorry for asking so many questions, but if we wanted to look at a concrete example, say I wanted to embed $\mathbb{R}P^{k}$ (using $k$ instead of $n$ to avoid confusion) into E-M space using the construction you've given, I would just have to pick some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, s.t. $1 < n < k$ and I would end up getting $K(\pi_{n}(\mathbb{R}P^{k}),n)$?

Comment: I don't know if it's an "abuse of notation" to use shorter letters, but yes when I say $K(G,n)$ i mean for our specific case $K(\pi_n(X),n)$ or whatever

Comment: Well $\mathbb{R}P^k$ doesn't satisfy the hypotheses of our statement, which are that it has no $k$-cells for $0<k<n$ so $\pi_k(X)$ has to be trivial. But $\mathbb{R}P^k$ has nontrivial $\pi_1=\mathbb{Z}/2$. But for example the embedding of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ into $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$, its inclusion as a subcomplex, would be an example. $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is a $K(\mathbb{Z},2).$